# No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root on Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, shell-exec

I am a Noob with the raspberry pi. I have it all setup and I am trying to run a file via the browser using `shell_exec`.

Here is the content of the python file:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

PIN_17 = 17 # Define LED colour and their GPIO pin
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(PIN_17, GPIO.OUT) # Setup GPIO pin

GPIO.output(PIN_17, True)  #Turn on
time.sleep (1)               #Wait
GPIO.output(PIN_17, False) #Turn off

GPIO.cleanup() #Useful to clear the board
```

I have the file in the directory `/home/pi/` called `trigger_pin.py`

I am trying to run the file through the browser using the PHP command below in `remote.php`:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("cd /home/pi/ && ./trigger_pin.py 2>&1"); //run command
echo "$output"; //output from command
?>
```

The output I am getting is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "./trigger_pin.py", line 9, in GPIO.setup(PIN_17, GPIO.OUT) # Setup GPIO pin RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!

Answer (score 4):

By default, the Raspberry Pi's GPIO interface requires superuser ("root") permissions. You may have a root-user shell open, therefore executing your Python script works without issues from the command line. Whereas, your PHP application server is likely running as another user.

The most straight-forward solution is to add the PHP application server's user (e.g., `www-data`) to `/etc/sudoers`, which will create a privileged user.

```
www-data  ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And then escalate your permissions with `sudo`:

```
shell_exec("cd /home/pi/ && sudo ./trigger_pin.py 2>&1");
```

*If you do this, be absolutely certain you verify the safety of what your Web server can execute (i.e., don't blindly install Web scripts with reviewing the source code).*

Alternatively, you can refactor your Python script to use [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/)'s `pigpiod` daemon, which runs with superuser privileges (so your application doesn't have to). Or you can use a separate tool that uses `setuid` to run as root such as Quick2Wire's [GPIO Admin](https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-gpio-admin).

You can also find more help at [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, where I just wanted a PHP script running through Apache to be able to trigger a GPIO pin high or low.

Running the Python script as my normal `pi` user would work, so it definitely doesn't require superuser privileges:

```
pi@my-pi:~ $ groups
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi
```

All you need to do—and this is a *lot* safer than adding the Apache web user as root—is add the web user to the `gpio` group, and restart Apache:

```
pi@my-pi:~ $ sudo usermod -a -G gpio www-data
pi@my-pi:~ $ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Then PHP should be able to run Python scripts that interact with the Pi's GPIO.

Answer (score -3):

Use this command

```
$ sudo python filename.py
```

Comment: OP is not running this from command line, rather exec'ing from a script called from web app.